# What is a PersistentCollection?

Tags: symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

I have a One-To-Many relationship in my database. The **editing, deleting and adding** of elements used to work just fine. However, after a few changes (I can't track them all back), it doesn't work anymore.
Now, when I fetch the object with the One-To-Many relationship, I get a Persistent Collection to represent my collection of the Many-side. I suppose that wasn't the case before. In my constructor, I create a new Array Collection and not a Persistent Collection.

I have looked up the doctrine documentation to find that:

> A PersistentCollection represents a collection of elements that have
>   persistent state.

I do not understand what that means.

Could you please tell me:

1. Is it normal to have Persistent Collections with a simple One-To-Many?
2. How do those collections may appear? (rather than the
       usual ArrayCollection)
3. Finally, what exactly is the use of a
           Persistent Collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.Is it normal to have Persistent Collections with a simple One-To-Many?

No, what is normal is the ArrayCollection, i never had to use PersistentCollection before, but it have some useful function that may be of use in some cases.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.1/class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html

2. How do those collections may appear? (rather than the usual ArrayCollection)

They are collections also they appear the same as a normal ArrayCollection having entities inside with their type.

3. Finally, what exactly is the use of a Persistent Collection?

As you can see in the documentation the PersistentCollection have a load of functions which ArrayCollection doesn't have, and PersistentCollection uses the EntityManager which allows an interaction with the database without having to persist, only flushing.

Comment: About point 2: I never asked for it, so I don't understand why it appears.

Comment: If you constructed your entity with arraycollection, then they shouldn't appear as persistentCollections. $this->foos = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();

Comment: @NawfalSerrar its not woking

Comment: Maybe out of the real topic but why persist a master with children in arraycollection reset the id of each child?

Answer (score 3):

To add to Serrar's description.

PersistentCollections only **notes** the connection to another Entity. Which is true if you properly made the OneToMany or ManyToOne mapping/link.

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
}
// @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comments", mappedBy="pages")
private $comments;
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->comments;
}
public function setComments(Comments $comments)
{
    $this->comments = $comments;
}
```

They don't give you the array data.

From the example above use the PageEntity's **getComments** method to pull in the comments related to the current Page. That assumes you have the page object.
Setting up the new ArrayCollection object in the construct is important:
 [Relationship Mapping Metadatalink](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#relationship-mapping-metadata)

[Doctrine: Class PersistentCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.PersistentCollection.html) - The description at the top describes the purpose.

Comment: The link Doctrine: Class PersistentCollection is broken.